# Dynamically adjusting css variables in a style sheet?

Tags: html, css, variables, dynamic, colors

I am currently building a template and have come across the following problem. I want the user to be able to choose a color, any color, based on a hex number that their theme will have. It is currently hardcoded into many places in my style.css file. What I want to know is what is the best way to go about this? I have looked into less.js and is this the best option for me to go with? I would also have to recode a lot of the css into it less. So the question is what is the best option for me? I don't want to convert style.css into php just so I can accomplish this... because I am sure there is a better way. This will also become a wordpress theme eventually so I want to know how to do it with that as well based on user settings.

Thank you.

Comment: the following question shows how to dynamically adjust the width. i'm sure you can adjust it to color aswell ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962837/how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-css-stylesheet-based-on-browser-width

Comment: It sounds like you already have your answer:  use dedicated CSS preprocessor (Sass, LESS, Stylus) or roll a primitive one one yourself in your server side language of choice.  Any choice is as good as any other for this task.

Comment: Well no these are different situations, however thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep user color or theme setting in options table and generate css file based on it. If configuration options are not too big consider dynamically putting it in file itself as inline css. It will override rules from external css.

If theme has predefined color schemes, separate theme rules in css files and place it as alternate stylesheets in html. Switch stylesheets files based on users color selection, using js.