# Change CSS class if window is less than ()

Tags: javascript, css

How to change a properties of a CSS class in case when browser window is shorter than 600px. Default properties are following:

```
.side { height:400px; width:700px; }
```

I want to change it to:

```
.side { height:300px; width:550px; }
```

when the window height is less than 600px.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically adjust css stylesheet based on browser width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962837/how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-css-stylesheet-based-on-browser-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
(function($) {

    var $sides = $('.side');

    var setCss = function() {
        if($(window).height() > 600) {
            $sides.css('width', 400).css('height', 700);
        } else {
            $sides.css('width', 300).css('height', 550);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setCss();
        $(window).resize(setCss);
    );

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 18):

Its called a media query:

```
@media all and (max-height: 600px) {
    .side { height:300px; width:550px; }
}
```

Comment: @watson I asked about window HEIGHT not WIDTH.

Comment: Yeah, just change width to height, as i did in my answer.

Comment: Here you can learn about media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Syntax