# Can and should a style sheet style every element in this HTML?

Tags: css

I'm developing a CMS plugin that generates HTML. I want to let users style the HTML any way they want. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ss:">
<table>
    <colgroup>
    <col span="1">
    <!-- span can range from 3 to 6. -->
    <col span="4">
    <col span="4">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Variable text goes here</th>
        <!-- span can range from 3 to 6. -->
        <th colspan="4">Responses</th>
        <th colspan="4">Percentage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- this row could contain from 6 to 12 headings -->
        <th>Small</th>
        <th>Med.</th>
        <th>Large</th>
        <th>Tot.</th>
        <th>Small</th>
        <th>Med.</th>
        <th>Large</th>
        <th>Tot.</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- one more more rows with this structure -->
    <tr>
        <th>1. What size Coke do you prefer?</th>
        <td>24</td>
        <!-- largest number surrounded by strong tags -->
        <td><strong>28</strong></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <!-- largest percent surrounded by strong tags -->
        <td><strong>54</strong></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I've placed the HTML inside div with an ID to allow users to select only elements within it. So my questions are:

Can a stylesheet style every element here without using classes, even if that means using pseudo-classes like nth-child?

Would that be a good practice? If not, what is a good strategy?

I could actually generate a class for every element, but where's the line between that's good and that's crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can a stylesheet style every element here without using classes, even if that means using pseudo-classes like nth-child?*
**Absolutely.** There are many ways to target elements. You would have to use `nth-child` once you get to all the `td`, `th` and `tr`s.

```
#ss:,
table,
colgroup,
col,
[span="1"],
[span="4"],
thead,
tr,
th,
[rowspan="2"],
[colspan="4"],
tbody,
td,
td strong {
    // css
}
```

*Would that be a good practice? If not, what is a good strategy?*
The argument against using `nth-child` is that the browser has to process every child element to do the math and find the correct elements, but with using classes or ids it can find the correct elements easier. So it's easier for the browser to process the css targeting classes and ids. I just read about browser processing nth-child this week, but I couldn't find the article for reference. I'm a big fan of this [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) page for `nth-child` references

*I could actually generate a class for every element, but where's the line between that's good and that's crazy?*
Everyone has their own definition of crazy. Giving rows a class would be helpful, then let the user get into the `nth-child` depth.`

Comment: Thanks for the decisive reply, and thanks for the link. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need IDs or classes? Just target the elements themselves

```
h1 {
  ...
}

h2 {
  ...
}

h3 {
  ..
}

etc...
```

You can target your stylesheets dynamically like in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962837/how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-css-stylesheet-based-on-browser-width).

Also for the record, DOM look-ups by class are significantly faster than by ID. A quick Google search on that will tell you more than I ever could.