# Remove or hide images based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In a piece of angular JavaScript, there is an `ng-repeat` command that prints a line of small images.

I need this line to not overlap into two lines when the browser window is re-sized. Thus, if the size gets too small, instead of pushing some of these down into a second line, it should just hide them or remove some of them.

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Is it possible to do this using only CSS?

Comment: Please make an effort and return with a specific question.

Comment: It's called "responsive design".

Comment: The best I can help you is to look into media queries and display , visiblity property of css.

Comment: Possibly Looking for this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962837/how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-css-stylesheet-based-on-browser-width

Comment: you can simply use css3 `@media queries`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with only css. You will have to use [media](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries) queries and decide the ranges in which you want your elements to appear and disappear

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
        myelement {
          display: none;
        }
 }

@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
        myelement {
          display: block;
        }

 }
```

These will also handle when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 6):

This is called [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). You'll want to use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) or a CSS library like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which has [responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide/show elements based on target window/device size.

Media query example:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  img#yourImage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Working media query demo: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/oXxKLe

---

Bootstrap example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="hidden-xs" src="http://i.imgur.com/1XKZPVe.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Working bootstrap demo: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/ZGWgpb

Bootstrap is just using media queries in its own stylesheet. It's just nice to have a stylesheet with predefined classes for a range of different devices so you don't have to craft your media queries yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done with css

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
   .myClass{
       display: none;
   }
}
```